# regex to check beginning and end of string for characters

Tags: regex, perl

I've got the following regex

```
^[\<\!\-\-]\w+?\W?[\-\-\>]$
```

It is supposed to check the start of a string for `<!--` and end of a string for `-->` with any number of characters in between, including all punctuation and can occur more than once in a string.
for example `<!--something here? or even this!. -->` would return true
and also `<!--some--><!--thing-->` would return true

I also want to create another regex that will replace the `<!--` and `-->` with a blank string.
The regex doesn't seem to work. How can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't seem to work?  What do you have thus far?

Comment: @Miller when i test it on debuggex it does not return true https://www.debuggex.com/r/7LwY_l0yjMKqCo2C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use of a character `[]` with `[\<\!\-\-]` doesn't make any sense.

To match for that string, all you need is `<!--.*?-->`

If you want it bounded to the whole string, then yes, you can add the `^` and `$` to produce: `^<!--.*?-->$`.

Comment: thanks. 
If i wanted to search the string for `<!--` and `-->` with a white space, how would the regex be?

Comment: `<!-- -->`  Unless a string contains a regular expression special character, you can just use it literally.  If you're unsure if a string contains a special character, just run [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) on it and see if anything is escaped.

Comment: @Miller: `quotemeta` isn't an indication of whether a given character is a regex metacharacter. It escapes everything except *word* characters, i.e. alphanumerics or underscore. It would escape every character in `<!--` just as the OP had. The full range of regex metacharacters is `\ .  ^  $  |  () [] {} * + ?` and `-` within a character class (square brackets).

Comment: Thanks @Borodin  I knew that at one point, but obviously forgot.  Reread the doc, as wasn't familiar with how quotemeta was effected by utf8.  So much for being clever.  Will just have to advise people to remember what the 12 regex special characters are: `\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .`